# Swift Parse Query how can i make uialertview after for object in objects?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uialertview

i'm doing parse query and i want to do UIAlertView after `for object in objects {}` done!, if i put the alertview inside the `for object in objects{//here}`, nothing happen, how can i detect when `for objects in objects {}` done then i show the alertview ??

the code looks like this:

```
var query = PFUser.query()

query = PFQuery(className: "_User")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

(object: [AnyObject]!, error:NSError?) -> Void in


for object in objects {

// alertview here not working, How can i make it after this loop done?


}

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = PFUser.query()

query = PFQuery(className: "_User")

// Heads up, entering background thread, may take some time to update the UI, maybe add an activity indicator even?
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

for object in objects as! [PFObject] {

// alertview here not working, How can i make it after this loop done?
// This would make an alert for every found object

}

// Anything after the for loop will happen after it completes, so if you put something here it will execute, suggest dispatching anything UI related to the main queue 

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        // visual interface stuff should happen here

    })

}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I think dispatch_async worked after the loop that's good, but i got an empty message like this "[]" just a square! i have a (`var msg = [String]()"` and in the loop `self.msg.append(object["message"] as String!)`, and in alertview showing the msg var like this `"\(self.msg)" `.. what's wrong? why the msg not showing up!

Comment: are you sure the messages are getting added? temporarily add a print statement inside of the for loop and print each object: println(object) - just to verify the data is there.

Comment: I did println(object) , but nothing showing up also if i type println("test"), what's wrong ?

Comment: Your query is not returning any results, the Parse.com User class is usually restricted to the current user only. I'm not sure if you can set custom ACLs on each user but that may help you.